# Parsing xml with prefix

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

How would I parse the following territory value using `lxml` ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<mstns:NewDataSet xmlns:mstns="AscentMetadataReport" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <mstns:Report>
        <mstns:Metadata>
            <mstns:Detail_Collection>
                <mstns:Detail>
                    <mstns:Territory>ARGENTINA</mstns:Territory>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
node=etree.fromstring(contents)
territory = node.find('NewDataSet/Report/Metadata/Detail_collection/Detail/Territory')
```

Though the above is not working. How would I parse the territory here?

Comment: I know nothing about Python, but in C#, one has to use a XmlNamespaceManager to be able to parse XML with prefixes. You probably need to do something similar in Python.

Comment: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785629/good-python-xml-parser-to-work-with-namespace-heavy-documents) that seems to be related to your problem.

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja: For comments, you have to use the `[text](url)` syntax for links.

Comment: Yeah, that was meant to be an answer. Stackoverflow auto-converted my answer to a comment :/

Answer (score 0):

Use a namespace here:

http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces

```
territory = node.find('mstns:ISOCountry',namespaces={'mstns':'AscentMetadataReport'}).text
```